# Fetch call stuck on promise and never returns

Tags: javascript

I have the following where I am trying to fetch details from a rest call via fetch api.

It looks like the call is made successfully but I never get the result.

When I console log as follows, I end up with getting following print out showing that it is still

stuck on promise and never got the result, yet I did enter the **then** block proving there is no errors

and data was fetched. Why am I not getting my json results, What am I doing wrong?

This is the print out from console within **then** block.

> Response is [object Promise] [object Promise]

This is the fetch call.

```
export function load() {
  return {
    allData: () => {
      return fetch(`someurl.com`)
        .then(response => {
          const value = response.json();
          console.log(`Response is ${response} ${value}`); // print out above
          return value;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(`Response is ${e}`);
        });
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: `response.json()` is *also* asynchronous.

Comment: You need another `then`, since you're returning the Promise that is returned by `.json()`. That second `then`'s function will be called with the parsed data. See [MDN's tutorial on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: So: `fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(val => {console.log(val); return val ;})`